# How to remove all account information in Windows 8 O/S

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts, privacy

I have to return a *Windows 8 Acer Aspire laptop* to the manufacturer and wish to remove all my account information.

I've had the machine for one day only and not much has been installed.
What is the best way to ensure that all the account information has been removed?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to clear the event data and recent places.

1. Make a new 'Blank' Account
2. Login to your new account
3. Delete your old account

   - You need to do it like this as you cannot delete the account you're currently logged in on.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new local account, delete your old account, then run a secure erase on the /user/username folder using a file wiping tool. Ideally I'd also want to run a reset, but this may need a windows 8 disk - this should wipe out your new account as well, and restore windows to a fresh state.